# Hidden input requires text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had someone help me out and get this code.

```
<input type="hidden" id="charge_total" value="charge_total">
```

And this JavaScript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("charge_total").value = document.getElementById("system_cost").innerHTML;
```

My problem is that it the host payment system I am using requires the hidden input to have a name.

So the hidden input must be like this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="charge_total" name="charge_total" value="charge_total">
```

My problem is using the code is it doesn't input any text into the field and I am left with a blank total in the check out page. I need this span ID to output whatever number it has into the hidden value input in this line of code.

```
<p>Total: <span id="system_cost">&nbsp;</span></p>

<input type="hidden" id="charge_total" name="charge_total" value="charge_total">
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?

---

Here is how I put it in the header.

```
<script>
$(function(){ //on document ready attach handlers
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting and do work
    $('#charge_total').val(parseFloat($('#system_cost').text()));
    $(this).submit(); //now submit the form, calculations are done
});
});
</script>
```

And these are the other two lines.

```
<input type="hidden" name="charge_total" value="charge_total">

<p>Total: <span id="system_cost">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

The span shows on the page like it is suppose to and populates correctly. It's only the hidden value that just shows charge_total.

Comment: does the `span` need to have the total amount or the `input`?

Comment: You can probably capture the form submit, stop it, grab the text from the span, place it as the value o the hidden input, then submit the form when calculations are done.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't explain this right. Basically I have a table that will add up the total and put the total into the span. I need the total to go from the span and into the hidden value.

Comment: Are you including JQuery on your page? If not then the above won't do anything other than error.

Comment: I don't have JQuery but I do have other JS on the page.

Comment: The script you have been so kindly 'given' requires JQuery to run it. Try adding that above the JQuery script. It'll probably work. Also, using **JS** to do calculations for a **payment** system? Let me know what the site is so I can hack it..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){ //on document ready attach handlers
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting and do work
        $('#charge_total').val(parseFloat($('#system_cost').text()));
        this.submit; //now submit the form, calculations are done
    });
});
```

Comment: @Taylor Watson No. You just put it in script tags at the head, and also wrap in document ready. see updated answer.

Comment: Ok I put it in the header with script tags and it still shows up at the checkout as "charge_total" without quotes inside the total box. I updated my question

Comment: The input comes from a form but the JS is in another file. Thats the one that does all the calculations. Honestly I have just been trying to set up this store for my website forever. Do you have paypal? I'm sure I am missing just a small detail. Could you fix it and I pay you?

Comment: Ohgodwhy is there anything else you can think of?